# Why does SOLR not work with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, solr

I used jQuery's `$.ajax()` to send requests to SOLR server and fetch results in JSON but it didn't work. My code was correct and thus I could not figure out what was wrong. If I paste the URL in the address bar of the browser, I get correct the JSON output.

I Googled it and found some similar questions on Stack Overflow: one question said to use `$.getJSON` instead, without giving any reason, but that also didn't work for me.

Now, I know there is a AJAX-SOLR framework and I am going to use it, but I would like to know why there are issues with SOLR and jQuery.

Following is my attempt at using `$.getJSON`, in case it turns out to be my mistake.

```
$('#searchForm').on('submit', function(){
    // get the user entered search query
    var query = $('#queryBox').val();

    // send the AJAX request to solr and get the results
    $.getJSON('http://localhost:8983/solr/select/?q='+query+'&wt=json&indent=true', function(searchResult){
        alert('success');
    });

    alert(query);

    return false;
});
```

I don't get the 'success' alert. The callback function is never executed. How can I fix this?

Comment: You can only make cross-domain requests if the server supports it (i.e. it enabled CORS). Or you have to use JSONP. But you cannot load JSON from a different domain without CORS.

Comment: @MaryMelody your rejection of larissa's [suggested edit](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5760271) to this question was, I think, wrong. You reject-and-edited but all you did was drop some valid corrections and improvements from her suggestion and introduce additional grammar errors; it would have been better to accept the suggestion. See Meta discussion at http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271298/is-it-worth-re-editing-when-a-reviewers-reject-and-edit-fails-to-fix-problems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is small mistake done in the URL you given.

```
$.getJSON('http://localhost:8983/solr/select/?q='+query+'&wt=json&indent=true', function(searchResult){


$.getJSON('http://localhost:8983/solr/select?q='+query+'&wt=json&indent=true', function(searchResult){
```

I Just removed the '/' after select . I just works fine using AJAX code below.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

function callAjax() {

    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
      xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
      } else {
      xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }
    alert(xmlhttp);
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
      {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
        document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
      }
    var searchStr = document.getElementById("searchQuery");
    xmlhttp.open("GET","http://localhost:8080/solr/select?q="+(searchStr.value),true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}

</script>
<title>ajaxTest</title>
</head>
<body>
<form>
<input type="text" id="searchQuery">
<input type="button" value="SUBMIT" onclick="callAjax()">

<div id="myDiv"></div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope it might be useful.

Answer (score 2):

Check [Documentation](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolJSON#JSON_specific_parameters)

Be sure you add the `json.wrf=?` parameter to the request URL, so the success method is called.

> json.wrf=function - adds a wrapper-function around the JSON response,
>   useful in AJAX with dynamic script tags for specifying a JavaScript
>   callback function.

You can still use the getJson function directly to get the json response from Solr.